# How do I get rid of the black square on my screen?

Tags: login-screen

I have this black screen on my desktop computer screen that appears after choosing my log in name. I can however use a guest account. can anyone help me as to how to get rid of it? I have no clue about the terminology, or what is  where. so any answers would have to be step by step.

[image: black square on screen]

Comment: What is the black square on your screen? Is it the black outline when a notification pops out? <- usually happen if your graphics card has problems.